# Capture CheckBox list input- and assign to text area-

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am developing a web application using asp.net and MySQL. in my app, users can add recipes. It is a record that will be inserted. I have to input the ingredients in to the database as well. I am trying to capture the input ingredients ( which are in the form of checkboxes. ) Please review the GetIngredientsInput() method. I am checking which check boxes are checked, and saving the TEXT of the item checked. I want to capture the input in form of list. ( list of strings. ) I used StringBuilder for this, and assign it to a textarea control. But the code doesn't seem in effect. Thanks in advance.

```
   protected void AddRecipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetIngredientsInput();
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=FreedomKitchen;Uid=root;Password=;");
        con.Open();
        String strcmd = "insert into Recipes(Recipe_ID,Food_Category,Meal_Category,Recipe_Name,All_Ingredients,Recipe_Description,Recipe_Instructions) values(@Recipe_ID,@Food_Category,@Meal_Category,@Recipe_Name,@All_Ingredients,@Recipe_Description,@Recipe_Instructions)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strcmd, con);
        MySqlCommand cmd_two = new MySqlCommand("select * from Recipes", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd_two;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Rows");
        int row_count = ds.Tables["Rows"].Rows.Count;
        r_id = row_count + 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Recipe_ID", r_id));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Food_Category", DropDownFoodCat.Text.ToString()));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Meal_Category", DropDownMealCat.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Recipe_Name", txtRecipeName.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@All_Ingredients", txtAllIngredients.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Recipe_Description", txtDescription.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Recipe_Instructions", txtInstructions.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();        
    }

    public  void GetIngredientsInput() {
        foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxListVeg.Items) {
            if (li.Selected) {

                     String ing_name=li.Text.ToString();
                str_ing_name.Append(ing_name);
                str_ing_name.Append("\n");
                txtAllIngredients.Text = ing_name = li.Text.ToString();
            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
 public string GetIngredientsInput()
 {
    StringBuilder str_ing_name = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxListVeg.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
        {
            String ing_name = li.Text.ToString();                
            str_ing_name.Append(ing_name);
            str_ing_name.Append(",");

        }
    }
    return str_ing_name.ToString(); 
 }




  protected void AddRecipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
             txtAllIngredients.Text= GetIngredientsInput();

       // Rest of code
  }
```

Comment: That doesnt work. Still the txtAllIngredients remain empty.